# Assign non identity sequence to field based on another column on Update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have an SQL table in SQL Server 2008 which for this purpose includes
Patient_id (Primary), Custno (Char), Recip_Id (Int)

```
1 - C01731 -    1  
2 - C01731 -    2  
3 - C01731 -    3  
4 - C01732 -    1  
5 - C01732 -    2  
6 - C01732 -    3  
7 - C01732 -    4  
8 - C01733 -    1  
9 - C01733 -    2
```

So the stored procedure I am using to move records which would basically reassign the Custno is as follows...

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[JR_SP_BatchMovePatients]

```
@IDs tblDeletePatients Readonly,
@CustnoTo varchar(max)

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @rownum int
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UsersMailingData WHERE custno = @CustnoTo)
SET @rownum = (select MAX(recip_id)+1 FROM UsersMailingData WHERE custno = @CustnoTo);
ELSE
SET @rownum = 0;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
With Summary AS (
Select UsersMailingData.Patient_id, 
        UsersMailingData.custno,
        UsersMailingData.Recip_id, 
        row_number() over (order by Custno)+@rownum AS NewNum   
FROM UsersMailingData
WHERE Patient_ID IN (Select Patient_id FROM  @IDs))
UPDATE Summary
SET Custno = @CustnoTo, Recip_id = NewNum
END
```

However because I can not use row_number() in this manner I am having a hard time completing this task.  So I am passing a table of Patient_id's which match the Patient_id's I want to update and I need to update the Custno field to the @CustnoTo value while reassigning the Recip_id based on the highest Recip_id in the @CustnoTo value.

So if I was moving C01732 to C01731 the results would be as follows...

```
1 -  C01731 -    1
2 -  C01731 -    2
3 -  C01731 -    3
4 -  C01731 -    4
5 -  C01731 -    5
6 -  C01731 -    6
7 -  C01731 -    7 
8 -  C01733 -    1
9 -  C01733 -    2
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you use row_number??? From what you posted it looks like row_number is exactly what you should be using. You just need to add a partition to the window "over(partition by Patient_ID order by Patient_ID"

Comment: I didn't think you could use row_number in an update since it is not in a select.  I get a Windowed Functions can only appear in the select or oder by clauses error

Comment: @SeanLange I was able to make the edited code above work.  Do you see any issues with using this logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try combination of below queries:

```
update UsersMailingData
set Custno=@CustnoTo
where Custno=@oldCustno

update u
    set recip_id=r
(select recip_id,row_number() over (partition by Custno order by Patient_id) as r from UsersMailingData )u
```

And your Sp should be like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[JR_SP_BatchMovePatients]

@oldCustno varchar(max),
@CustnoTo varchar(max)

AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

update UsersMailingData
set Custno=@CustnoTo
where Custno=@oldCustno

   update u
    set recip_id=r
(select recip_id,row_number() over (partition by Custno order by Patient_id) as r from UsersMailingData )u

END
```

Comment: I get a Windowed Functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses error when I try to use row_number in the UPDATE

Comment: Edited code for what appears to be working.  Any issues you see using this logic?

Comment: @JRoy Thank you for pointing out the error. I've improved the query and tested it.